# Can not delete deployment on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I installed Kubernetes **version 10**

```
 kubectl version
 Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead",GitTreeState:"archive", BuildDate:"2018-03-29T08:38:42Z",GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
 Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10",  GitVersion:"v1.10.0",  GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"archive", BuildDate:"2018-03-29T08:38:42Z", 
 GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

When i execute :

```
kubectl delete deployment example
Error: unknown command "verion" for "kubectl"
```

it is not useful here to put --force Or --cascade=false ==> I tried all this put there is no change

When I execute :

```
 kubectl get nodes ==> Master return Nodes , it is Okay
```

Any help ?

Comment: Have you conflated your error messages, or does running that `kubectl delete` command actually say `Error: unknown command "version"` right after it?

Comment: thank you Sir , i Solved it can you check my answer plz :D

Comment: Without the accurate error message, I doubt anyone can tell you whether that's a good solution or not, but I guess if it works then I'm glad to hear it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it 
By putting the Right ca.crt and server.key in the Controller-manager :

```
/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager

KUBE_CONTROLLER_MANAGER_ARGS="--root-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt --service-account-private-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.key"
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue where I could not delete a deployment with Kubernetes installed in Docker Desktop. The solution has been going to `Docker Desktop > Preferences > Reset Kubernetes cluster.`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
kubectl get all
```

This lists all the pods, service, deployment, replicaset, job and cronjobs.
from this you can know the name of deployment you want to delete.

```
kubectl delete <name of deployment as displayed from get all command>
```

Comment: your answer doesn't solve issue of this topic